# Story about a boy who made a device to make things disappear

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, lafferty

Help to find a really short story about small boy from large family who made a really simple device (IIRC it consisted of tin can and two paper circles) which could make things disappear if you look at them through it and blink.
Some other points I remember:

- First thing he made disappear was cat
- He did't invent the device but read about it in a little sister diary
- Said sister told that she knows how return all items and requested some stuff. In the end all that stuff was actually just something she wanted for herself.
- She has destroyed golden watch for "dramatic moment"
- In the end she just told that all items would return exactly 7 days after disappearence, as boy built 7-days version of the device
- She mentioned that she tried to make longer-working version of the device, but couldn't because it requires blood from a heart of young boy, and her little brother screamed too much when she tried to make a cut

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange. For future reference, please read [our guidance](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/9335/30482) on asking good story-ID questions.

Comment: @PeregrineRook It looks like Revolver_Ocelot already knows how to ask good story-ID questions.

Comment: Well, he or she provided a good synopsis of the *plot* of the story, which was enough for Doug O to provide a correct answer. However, the question is lacking the standard metadata. For example, was the story read in hardcover or paperback? What was on the cover? Any information about the author? When was the story read, and how old was it then? Where was it read, and was it in English? Other details are listed in [the guidance](//meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/9335/30482 "How to ask a good story-ID question?") and the [tag wiki](//scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The story is ["Seven-Day Terror"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?40956) by [R A Lafferty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R._A._Lafferty).  One of his best.  You can find it in one of the ["Year's Best SF"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?33512) anthologies edited by Judith Merrill.  Sorry I can't recall exactly which Year.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to search for it and found [its `isfdb` entry under name _Seven-day terror_](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?40956). Later I found excerpts which confirmed that it is indeed the story I was looking for.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot You can read it at [archive.org](https://archive.org/stream/1962-03_IF_modified#page/n93/mode/2up).